# PHP SOAP return array value

Tags: php, soap

I am connecting to a webservice using SOAP and PHP. Now i getting result value as an array I think.

```
try
{
    $result = $soapClient->__soapCall("GetTrafficIdByLicenseInfo", array($parameters), null, $soapHeaders, $output_headers);    
}
```

When I `print_r($result);`
it will print

```
stdClass Object
(
[GetTrafficIdByLicenseInfoResult] => stdClass Object
    (
        [intFLSCode] => 0
        [lngSerial] => 0
        [lngTrafficID] => 1130175832
    )
)
```

I want to print each these 3 variables separately. How can I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your SOAP API request appears to be returning an object, so you want to print/echo the result like this:

```
echo $result->GetTrafficIdByLicenseInfoResult->intFLSCode;
echo $result->GetTrafficIdByLicenseInfoResult->lngSerial;
echo $result->GetTrafficIdByLicenseInfoResult->lngTrafficID;
```